# A webserver as a printer?

Tags: networking, printing

I am trying to figure out what technology would allow me to have a web server that I control show up as a printer in Chrome. This would be added manually by the user. But I don't know what governs the printers that show up in Chrome. I notice when you click on "manage" it opens your OS's settings... so I guess maybe it can't be a webserver but has to be a specific protocol?

In that case I'm wondering if you need a VPN to do that and then the fake printer would get added by VPN/network.

The intent is to get the files being printed and then on the server side be able to store it or download it to some other client.

This is a specific use case it's not about just file upload/download that I can do. But I am specifically looking for the printing aspect. Like a printer API.

Or am I looking at writing our own desktop software that would be the fake printer and then that connects to our web server to upload the files intending to be printed?

Comment: Simply print to PDF and upload it to the server. No programming required.

Comment: That's not the point. It's avoiding uploading/using the printing process as the upload

Comment: I’m afraid you indeed have to go through the operating system procedures to add a new printer, virtual or real. I’m not sure whether unprivileged users have the required permissions to do so.

Comment: This is okay, it's not strangers the users would be walked through how to do this. I just needed to know if it was possible/how. So I'm glad to hear that it is, now I gotta do it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any host can disguise as a network printer, as long as it speaks the same protocol – that's how print servers work. Most operating systems will allow you to add a network printer by its URL.

There are a few standard print job submission protocols that are spoken by network printers – **IPP** (port 631), **HP JetDirect** (port 9100), and occassionally **lpr** (port 515).

Out of those, [IPP](https://www.pwg.org/ipp/ippguide.html) is the most interesting choice for you, both because it is in fact HTTP-based (i.e. you could implement it on a webserver), and because of the 'IPP Everywhere' standard for driverless printing, which allows print jobs to be submitted in the form of standard PDF files instead of requiring a vendor-specific driver.

Implementing IPP from scratch may be complex; however, the Linux/macOS 'CUPS' software, although mostly used for local printing, is actually an IPP server at its core – it's possible that you could configure it to have a fake queue that just stores jobs on the filesystem, somehow.

And if you cannot get clients to submit jobs as "driverless" PDF files, then look for a driver that submits jobs in the PCL5 format (which Ghostscript can convert to PDF for previewing, and your printers most likely accept PCL5 straight on port 9100). At this point, you don't necessarily need to use IPP – you could also write a server that accepts the same print jobs via JetDirect or lpr instead.

---

Additional explanation:

Keep in mind that printing *does not send the original files* to the printer. Whether you're printing a PDF or a DOC or a JPEG, the client always rasterizes it into some sort of generic format, so the network printer (or your print server, in this case) only receives jobs in that final raster format – it won't know anything about the original.

That means it's not enough to implement just the network protocol – you will also need to un­der­stand the raster format that the client sends you. (This depends on the printer driver used by the client; e.g. printing through a Kyocera driver will generate KPDL-format print jobs.) This is where 'IPP Everywhere' comes in – if you want to receive PDFs, you will have to pretend to be a "driverless" printer that uses PDF as its raster format.

It *also* means that printing will lose all "digital" features of the original document. Even if you're printing a PDF *to* a PDF-based printer, you'll still most likely lose features like fillable forms or digital signatures in the process.

Comment: I did stumble across CUPS but wasn't sure if I understood what it was for. My concern was understanding the data/getting it as a renderable PDF. Anyway this sounds like it is doable so I'm going to look this up/try it out on a server and see if it works, thank you for understanding my intent.

Comment: Want to emphasize that driverless printing (with print jobs being actual PDF files) is a much later specification, it's not guaranteed by IPP in itself. But if the "driverless" part doesn't quite work out, look for a driver that submits jobs in the PCL5 format (which Ghostscript can convert to PDF for previewing, and your printers most likely accept PCL5 straight on port 9100).

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I definitely have no idea about printers/networking so this is good to know. Hopefully it works. There is also CUPs too if IPP doesn't work, I just need to get the files being printed and send them as a buffer or something.

Comment: Ah, if you're only buffering them for a specific real printer, then that's less of an issue -- in that case it's _probably_ going to work even if the client just uses an actual printer driver in the traditional way. (For example, all our workstations have a Kyocera driver installed and submit KPDL-format jobs -- they _think_ they're talking to a real network printer, even if it's actually just printserver software running on Windows.)

Comment: I might not be following, the end result is a user while in Chrome/browser can hit Print and see this fake printer in the list. The files (in this case batch PDFs) would get sent there and my server would get the files and then have them in memory to be sent to other clients related to this event in real time. And then their browser session would embed/render the PDF in front of them. I know it sound stupid why not just do file upload but it's a niche case.

Comment: My point was that printing _never_ sends the files as-is. Whether your originals were PDF or DOC or DWG, the client always _rasterizes_ it into some sort of generic format, so the network printer (or your print server, in this case) only receives jobs in that final raster format. (E.g. if you print a .docx file, the printer won't even know it was a .docx file.) So in order to receive PDFs, your server needs to pretend that it's an "IPP Everywhere" printer that _expects_ PDF-format jobs, and even then it might still receive a pre-processed PDF rather than the original.

Comment: I see I will keep that in mind. I also need the editable fields (you can type into) which I'm wondering if that'll be a problem.

Comment: It most likely will be. I wouldn't be surprised if such features got completely stripped by the client (after all, they wouldn't make any sense to a printer that puts stuff on paper). If you want to keep digital-only features, then going through the printing system might not be a good plan in the first place.

Comment: Well I guess I will find out, thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @JacobDavidC.Cunningham It sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What's the problem that actually needs solving, and that you think this virtual printing setup will solve?

Comment: It is an interop problem, dealing with locked in "software" if you will. Printers are universal so can deal with it that way. I've got what I need here. I'm not saying this is ideal, I agree file upload/download is way easier but we're trying to avoid that. Less clicks and wider application. Also in this case the PDFs are part of the sites, you could download them and then re-upload them or host them somewhere but yeah... it's more steps.

Comment: Well I did get it to work (printed home PDF file to remote cups-pdf server and downloaded said file back to my computer) -- and... the editable fields are stripped out. Going to see what my options are.